# What is wrong with my Ajax Javascript when submitting or displaying a form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajaxform

The code below SHOULD be opening an 'add' form and allowing Ajax to send the response back to the server. I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to this and I can't find what's wrong with it. In the Developers Console, it says the problem is with the `xhr.send();` line. Can you tell me what I need to change to get this to work?

```
   function DisplayForm() {
   var div = document.getElementById("formDiv");
   div.classList.toggle("show");

   div.innerHTML = '<img class="loadingImg" src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." height="60" width="60" border="0">';

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', "add.php", true);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            DisplayAfterLoad(data);
            var button = document.getElementById("saveForm");
            button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               recordAdd();
            });
         }
      }
   }

   xhr.send();

}
```

It shows the "loading.gif" but does nothing else.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the exact phrasing of the error you're receiving.

Comment: Do you need to include parameters in `xhr.send()`?

Comment: @devlincarnate: The error I see just says "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: @user1599011: Um, I don't know. I didn't think so...

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error, it means your AJAX request is working but the server side file `add.php` is throwing an error. Check your PHP error logs.